# Combine cucumber json reports

Tags: java, json, gradle, cucumber, testng

I am writing test cases using cucumber, and testNG using Java 17.

We created multiple feature files and for each feature, we have a separate runner class.

Confucurtion of the runner class looks as below:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/wallet/A.feature"},
        glue = {"com.test.a"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:build/cucumber-reports/a.json"})
@Test(groups = {"A", "regression"}, alwaysRun = true)
public class RunnerA extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/wallet/B.feature"},
        glue = {"com.test.b"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:build/cucumber-reports/b.json"})
@Test(groups = {"B", "regression"}, alwaysRun = true)
public class RunnerB extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

When I run the test case it generates 2 JSON files in `cucumber-reports` folder as `a.json` and `b.json`.

How can I merge these two json files in one single json file ie. `report.json`

I am using `gradle 7` as a build tool with `cucumber 7.11.0`

End goal: I want to upload json file in [Xray](https://www.getxray.app/) using [API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-CucumberJSONresults)

Comment: You said "for each feature, we have a separate runner class." Why? why can't you use tags to run the cases?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by writing a custom gradle task.

Here is my solution:

Gradle task:

```
task aggregatReport(type: JavaExec) {
    println("Running aggregatReport task")
    description 'Combine multiple cucumber report json file into one json file'
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "com.ReportAggregator"
    def reportFolderPath = "./build/cucumber-reports/";
    File file = file(reportFolderPath);
    args file.toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString()
}
```

The code:

```
public class ReportAggregator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ReportAggregator with argument -> " + Arrays.toString(args));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File reportFolder = new File(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Report folder  -> " + reportFolder.isDirectory() + " " + reportFolder.exists());
        List<Path> reportFiles = Files.walk(reportFolder.toPath()).filter(file -> file.toFile().getName().endsWith(".json")).toList();
        List<Map<String, Object>> finalReportList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (CollectionUtil.isNotEmpty(reportFiles)) {
            System.out.println("Total report file ->" + reportFiles.size());
            reportFiles.forEach(path -> {
                try {
                    String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(path.toFile(), Charset.defaultCharset());
                    TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {
                    };
                    List<Map<String, Object>> hashMaps = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
                    finalReportList.addAll(hashMaps);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Can not read file -> " + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            });

            if (CollectionUtil.isNotEmpty(finalReportList)) {
                String finalReportFileName = reportFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/final.json";
                File finalReportFile = new File(finalReportFileName);
                if (finalReportFile.exists()) {
                    boolean delete = finalReportFile.delete();
                    System.out.println("File is deleted -> " + delete);
                }
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(finalReportFile, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(finalReportList), Charset.defaultCharset());
                System.out.println("Report file created");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Empty report is created");
                throw new ReportException("Empty report created");
            }
        } else {
            throw new ReportException("No report file found under folder ->" + reportFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

and gralde task dependency settings:

```
test {
    println("Running test task")
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/testng.xml'
    }
    finalizedBy aggregatReport
}


task importJunitResultsToXrayCloud() {
    dependsOn 'test'
    description 'Imports Cucumber test results to Xray Test Management for Jira Cloud.'

    doLast {
       //code to upload report
    }
}
```

and to upload report just run  `./gradlew importJunitResultsToXrayCloud`